# How to find the equations of a spherical ellipse-shaped surface

Tags: geometry, 3d, surfaces, spheres

This is a surface created by drawing an ellipse on a sphere. It can be considered that the sphere is at the origin and the center of the ellipse is on the $x$-axis. I show an image to make it clearer what I mean. What I want is to find the equations of the surface in yellow.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How is the ellipse drawn?  Is this like an elliptical sticker on the surface of a sphere?  In that case, are you sure it remains an ellipse? It is a deformed ellipse, but it may not be an ellipse anymore.

Comment: You could set the radius of the sphere, say, $r = 1$, and mention the "radii" of the elliptical sticker.

Comment: Have you tried using the [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection)?

Comment: I had not thought about it. In the image the ellipse is created by intercepting a sphere with an elliptical base cylinder which is probably the simplest way to do it.

Comment: the radius is a constant greater than 0.

Comment: Why don't you fix the radius of the sphere? Have you tried anything and gotten stuck?